# convert date object to datestring in TZ format javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My input is

```
var dt = "06/01/2018"
var time = "06:25:00"
```

i want output to be in string like this `"2018-06-01T00:55:00.000Z"`.

I did `var result = new Date(dt+time); //output is object here`

I want to convert that object to string. Can any one tell me how to do that.

Comment: Do look at `moment.js` for more complex date manipulations :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a `Date` object if the `dt` and `time` formats are known in advance. Here is how you can do it

```js
const dt = '06/01/2018';
const [mm,dd,yyyy] = dt.split('/')
const time = '06:25:00';
const date = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}T${time}.000Z`;
console.log(date);
```

Comment: here reverse does wrong because of mm/dd/yyy it reverses to yyyy-dd-mm but i need yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: const dt = '06/01/2018';
const [mm,dd,yyyy] = dt.split('/');
var time = "06:25:00";
const date = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}T${time}.000Z` 
This worked thanks for ur solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dt = '06/01/2018';
var time = "06:25:00";
console.log(new Date(`${dt} ${time}`).toJSON())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dt = "06/01/2018";
var time = "06:25:00";
var date_test = new Date((dt + ' ' + time)).toString();
console.log(date_test);
```

Comment: it still returns object instead of string

Comment: I just forget to add the toString() method, now it's right

Comment: I just voted positive your answer thanks for ur reply.